# Can I use First() and Concat() on my list at same time

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list and I want to remove nulls from it and then concatenate it with the other list as well.

Can I do it using LINQ? e.g.

```
ViewBag.BackUPDestinationList = ServiceBackupList.Select(x =>
new SelectListItem()
{
Value = x.ServerInstanceId.ToString(),
Text = x.SPPServerName,
Group = group1
}).Concat(ServiceBackupList.Select(x =>
new SelectListItem()
{
Value = x.NodeGuid.ToString(),
Text = x.SPServerName,
Group = group2
})).ToList();
```

in above i am using two selectlstitems and concatenating them but i want to check if my Text e.g. x.SPPServerName or x.SPServerName are empty or null dont include them .
 IF i use First() it gives error in using Concate() also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could filter both collection prior to creating SelectListItem. Consider the following example,

```
ServiceBackupList.Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SPPServer))
                .Select(x =>
                     new SelectListItem()
                     {
                       Value = x.ServerInstanceId.ToString(),
                       Text = x.SPPServerName,
                       Group = group1
                     })
                .Concat(ServiceBackupList
                .Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SPPServer))
                .Select(x =>
                     new SelectListItem()
                     {
                       Value = x.NodeGuid.ToString(),
                       Text = x.SPServerName,
                       Group = group2
                     })).ToList();
```

Comment: @haroonnasir mark it as correct answer if it helped.

Comment: yup have to wait 1 more minute before doing it so .. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove those using `Where` first and then populate the `SelectListItem` collection:

```
ServiceBackupList = ServiceBackupList
                      .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SPPServerName))
                      .ToList();
......  // code to populate in ViewBag
......
```

After that you can generate the collection of `SelectListItem`.

Comment: @haroonnasir glad it helped

Comment: But omit that ToList() after the Where(). It is just overhead, not needed.

Comment: @bommelding i asuume `ServiceBackupList` is declare as `List` that's why

Answer (score 0):

You can filter nulls first using `Where`:

```
ViewBag.BackUPDestinationList = ServiceBackupList
     .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SPPServerName)).Select(...)
     .Concat(ServiceBackupList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SPServerName))
     .Select(...));
```